# How do I change the tag used by Zend_View_Helpers_FormErrors?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

When using Zend_Form, if an element is not valid the form returns the errors by way of an unordered list. How do I change this to use paragraph tags instead?

I have attempted loading the Errors decorator for the elements and calling setOptions() to pass in a bunch of tags to replace the ul/li stuff being used by Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors, but that didn't work =/ Instead Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors just put the options as attribute/value pairs in the ul tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending the Errors decorator I have extended the formErrors view helper, getting it to accept and process the options in the array. The formErrors view helper has setters to let me change the tags being used:

```
class My_View_Helper_FormErrors extends Zend_View_Helper_FormErrors
{
    public function formErrors($errors, array $options = null)
    {
      if(key_exists('htmlElementStart', $options))
      {
        $this->setElementStart($options['htmlElementStart']);
        unset($options['htmlElementStart']);
      }
      if(key_exists('htmlElementEnd', $options))
      {
        $this->setElementEnd($options['htmlElementEnd']);
        unset($options['htmlElementEnd']);
      }
      if(key_exists('htmlElementSeparator', $options))
      {
        $this->setElementSeparator($options['htmlElementSeparator']);
        unset($options['htmlElementSeparator']);
      }
      return parent::formErrors($errors, $options);
    }
}
```

To pass options, I got the error decorator and setOptions() on it:

```
$element->getDecorator()->setOptions(
  array(
    'class' => 'error',
    'htmlElementStart' => '<p%s>',
    'htmlElementEnd' => '</p>',
    'htmlElementSeparator' => '<br/>'
  )
);
```

And tell the elements to load the helper path:

```
$element->getView()->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper');
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, you cannot change the output format by just passing a bunch of options.
If you like to change this behaviour you have no choice but to write your own Errors decorator (most likely a derivative from the original Errors decorator). This new decorator has to have its `render ()` method overwritten in order to be able to call your own view helper (instead of the `formErrors` helper which ZF uses by default).

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion and have already started doing this. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: The Errors decorator proxies to the formErrors helper (which we both already knew). Instead of overwriting the errors decorator render() method, I extended the formErrors view helper to accept and process the array of options.

Comment: That's exactly what I would do.